# Rename a webpage from C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

when we copy the aspx page from the directory and paste into another directory before pasting the aspx page how to rename the page with their CodeFile and Inherits keywords name is changed at the same time of renaming the page on button click event in c# asp.net..

Comment: What have you tried? Why? What are you actually trying to achieve?  If you rename a page and simply you app will not work anyway as the page has a backing class which you would need to rename/recompile again.  If you explain your problem maybe someone can offer other options.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VS to copy, (same name), then you can right click and choose re-name. it WILL update the aspx file (code behind setting for you). However, it does NOT update forms class name.

So, I renamed a aspx page from HotelGrid, to HotelGridABC

We now see this:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" 
   CodeBehind="HotelGridABC.aspx.vb" 
   Inherits="MyCalendar.HotelGrid" %>
```

You thus then change the inhertes to HotelGridABC

And then in the form, you change:

```
 Public Class HotelGrid
```

to

```
Public Class HotelGridABC
```

However, just rename should still work - and you don't actually have to re-name the inherits class, and the base class name in the code behind. But I recommend that you do.

So, it will automatic set and re-name the code behind file for you - but to my knowledge the automatic re-name of the forms class does NOT occur. As noted, you can leave it alone, but I would not.